# Send multiple mails in one deliver command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, email, actionmailer

I try to send multiple mails in one single `.deliver` command. My mailer method looks like this:

```
def feedback_mail
    @verteiler = ["foo@bar.com", "bar@foo.com"]
    for v in @verteiler.sort
      mail(:to => v, :subject => "Foo Bar")
    end
end
```

The problem is, only one mail gets send, to the last entry of the array. any advice here?

Comment: Why won't you prepare your emails first and then iterate on them calling deliver on each?

Comment: That's because you pass the array to `:to`, not each email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This idea won't scale much - you'd need to implement something like `Resque` and workers to process sending all the emails out.

Yes, @socjopata's idea is good, but you'll really want to iterate adding them to the job queue and spawn a couple workers to process them.  As per the guides, this is how to do it:

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :to => ["foo@bar.com", "bar@foo.com"],
          :from => "notification@example.com"

  def new_registration(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:subject => "New User Signup: #{@user.email}")
  end
end
```

I'd essentially hand of `YourMailer.feedback_mail(<PASS ARGS HERE>).deliver` to Resque-

```
Resque.enqueue(SendMail, <ARGS>)  # replace this in your controller
```

The worker would look like

```
#send_mail.rb
class SendMail
  @queue = :feedback_mail_queue
  def self.perform(<ARGS>) # pass these in enqueue call
    YourMailer.feedback_mail(<PASS ARGS HERE>).deliver
  end
end
```

As per [section 2.3.4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-methods) of the Rails Guides:

> It is possible to send email to one or more recipients in one email
>   (for e.g. informing all admins of a new signup) by setting the list of
>   emails to the :to key. The list of emails can be **an array of email addresses or a single
>   string** with the addresses separated by commas.

Looking back at your attempt, FYI - this should work

```
def feedback_mail
    @verteiler = ["foo@bar.com", "bar@foo.com"]
    mail(:to => @verteiler, :subject => "Foo Bar")
end
```

Comment: Sending the same email to multiple addresses works fine by passing an array as noted.  I have cases where I want to send different emails to different users as part of the same event.  So far the only solution that works is to have different mailer methods and different calls to `deliver`.

Answer (score 1):

This has taken me the better part of 1-2 weeks to figure out, so hopefully this code will give you some idea about what to do.

Here's my Lists controller where I generate the message to be sent to the mailer:

```
def messages
  @list = List.find(params[:id]) 
  #@message =  Message.new( :user_id => @list.user.id, :list_id => @list.id, 
  #:subject => params[:subject], :body => params[:body] )
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  @contacts = @list.contacts

   respond_to do |format|
     if @list.save && @message.save  

       #Blaster is my mailer, and blast is the send method in the blaster.rb mailer

       Blaster.blast(@message, @contacts)
       format.html { 
         redirect_to @list, notice: 'Message was saved.' }
         format.json { render json: @list, status: :created, location: @list }
     else
       format.html { redirect_to @list, notice: 'There was an error, try again'}
       format.json { render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
```

end

=========

Here's my mailer - it's called blast.rb

```
def blast(message, contacts)
    # can't send without a message, and an array of contacts 
    @message = message
    @contacts = contacts

    # with variables set, let's create the loop to do its magic 
    @contacts.each do |contact|
        mail = mail(
          :to => "#{contact.email}",
          :from => "noreply@foo.org",
          :return_path => "noreply@foo.org",  
          :subject => @message.subject,
          :body => @message.body
          #:template_path => 'blaster',
          #:template_name => 'blast'
          ) do |format|
            format.html { render 'blast.html.erb'}
            format.text { render 'blast.text.erb'}
            end   
        mail.deliver
    end # contacts.each loop
 end #blast method
```

I'm pretty sure this code is sub-optimal and of poor quality, so caveat emptor, but perhaps you'll find something in here that'll help you solve your unique implementation. Hope it helps!

D.